Three problems are stopping me from using RDP in the latest Ubuntu
Three problems.

Can't use GPU with remote login, so need to use desktop sharing.  I need Blender to use the GPU, which only seems possible when using desktop sharing rather than remote login.

Can't use Desktop sharing because the Login details change every reboot (I'm using auto login for the user).

Can't use without a monitor connected, even after trying GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset"
and xvfb virtual frame buffer.


Really stumped, here.  I can buy a hdmi emulator from amazon, but it seems pointless if I can't get Ubuntu to remember the desktop sharing login details rather than generating new ones every time.
Can anyone suggest a way to get rdp working without a monitor and so that apps on the host still use the GPU? Or an alternative.
I'm using wayland.  Enabling X11 broke everything.
Cheers
Michael
